# R - Subsetting to group of matrices based on a condition

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a matrix based on a specific value in a column. But I want my subsets in a number of separate matrices. For eg, say I have a matrix `ccc` which is

```
aaa=c(1,1,1,2,5,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,4)
bbb=c(4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7)
ccc=cbind(aaa,bbb)
```

I want to subset using a condition which is `ccc[,1]==1` and at the same time I want the subset to be divided into several matrices separated by a breaking point. The breaks are based on runs of `aaa==1`. To make it clear I need my outputs in the following way,

```
ddd1
     aaa bbb
[1,]   1   4
[2,]   1   4
[3,]   1   4

ddd2
aaa bbb 
  1   3 

ddd3
     aaa bbb
[1,]   1   3
[2,]   1   2

ddd4
     aaa bbb
[1,]   1   2
[2,]   1   2
[3,]   1   3
[4,]   1   4
[5,]   1   5
[6,]   1   6
```

`ddd1,..,ddd4` being the subset matrices. I hope I made it clear. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Your break points aren't clear at all. What's the logic behind the breaks? `ccc$aaa` also can't be used as you have a matrix and `$` only works for data.frames/lists. Did you mean to use `ccc <- data.frame(aaa,bbb)`?

Comment: @thelatemail The split is based on runs of `aaa==1`, I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split` and `cumsum`:

```
ccc <- data.frame(ccc)
split(ccc[ccc$aaa==1,], cumsum(ccc$aaa!=1)[ccc$aaa==1])

#$`0`
#  aaa bbb
#1   1   4
#2   1   4
#3   1   4
#
#$`2`
#  aaa bbb
#6   1   3
# 
#$`3`
#  aaa bbb
#8   1   3
#9   1   2
# 
#$`4`
#   aaa bbb
#11   1   2
#12   1   2
#13   1   3
#14   1   4
#15   1   5
#16   1   6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't used 'split' before. I was struggling with loops.